# How can I change the thickness of a specific line and/or add shape in a multi-line plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data called `molten.data` below. I have this code which plots the lines I want, but I need to change the thickness of one specific line (`G11F:G11M`) to make it look thicker compared to other lines or preferably add shape to the data point in that line. How can we do it?

code I have:

```
ggplot(molten.data, aes(variable, value,group= key.related,colour=key.related)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point()
```

data:

```
molten.data<- structure(list(key.related = c("G11F:G11F", "G11F:G11F", "G11F:G11F", 
"G11F:G11M", "G11F:G11F", "G11F:G11M", "G11F:AOGC-02-0079", "G11F:G11F", 
"G11F:G11M"), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("IBS_2_samples", "IBS_4_samples", "IBS_8_samples", 
"IBS_16_samples", "IBS_32_samples"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.533, 
1.01, 1.11, 0.132, 1.22, 0.353, 0.0658, 1.33, 0.534)), .Names = c("key.related", 
"variable", "value"), row.names = c(1L, 82L, 163L, 168L, 244L, 
249L, 260L, 325L, 330L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a column to note whether an observation should be highlighted, and map that to size, shape, linetype, etc.

You can do that with an `ifelse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

molten.data %>%
  mutate(hilite = ifelse(key.related == "G11F:G11M", 2, 1))
#>         key.related       variable  value hilite
#> 1         G11F:G11F  IBS_2_samples 0.5330      1
#> 2         G11F:G11F  IBS_4_samples 1.0100      1
#> 3         G11F:G11F  IBS_8_samples 1.1100      1
#> 4         G11F:G11M  IBS_8_samples 0.1320      2
#> 5         G11F:G11F IBS_16_samples 1.2200      1
#> 6         G11F:G11M IBS_16_samples 0.3530      2
#> 7 G11F:AOGC-02-0079 IBS_16_samples 0.0658      1
#> 8         G11F:G11F IBS_32_samples 1.3300      1
#> 9         G11F:G11M IBS_32_samples 0.5340      2
```

My preference is to do it with factors. `forcats::fct_other` lets you pick levels to keep, and labels everything else as "Other". Imagine you have several keys you want to keep with their original names, and a whole lot of keys you want to lump into an "Other" category—it becomes pretty useful as the data gets more complicated.

Then I pipe it into `ggplot`, using `hilite` to designate the highlighting. One way is with size; you can adjust the sizes to make it more dramatic, or get whatever sizes are appropriate:

```r
molten.data %>%
  mutate(hilite = as.factor(key.related) %>% fct_other(keep = c("G11F:G11M"), other_level = "Other keys")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, color = key.related, group = key.related, size = hilite)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    scale_size_manual(values = c("G11F:G11M" = 1.5, "Other keys" = 0.5), guide = F)
```

[image]

Or keeping size uniform but changing shapes. Here I set up the shape values so the non-highlighted points get a normal circle point and the highlighted points get triangles.

```r
molten.data %>%
  mutate(hilite = as.factor(key.related) %>% fct_other(keep = c("G11F:G11M"), other_level = "Other keys")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, color = key.related, group = key.related)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(shape = hilite), size = 2) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c("G11F:G11M" = 17, "Other keys" = 16), guide = F)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you need you can keep or remove size or linetype as shown below -

```
l <- ifelse(molten.data$key.related == 'G11F:G11M', 1, 2)
ltyp <- ifelse(molten.data$key.related == 'G11F:G11M', 'longdash', '“dotted”')

ggplot(data=molten.data, aes(x=variable, y=value, group= key.related, colour=key.related)) +
  geom_line(aes( linetype = ltyp , size = l )) +
  geom_point(aes( size = l ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vikash, but what are those black box/legend?

Comment: What is `l`? Also, why do you include `linetype` in the `geom_point` call?

Comment: @MAPK black legend are the size.

Comment: Sorry `l` was supposed to be `size` and by copy-paste, I pasted `ltyp` also in `geom_point`.  Thank you @markus for pointing out.